# Increasing the Width of the MatBottomSheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

The following CSS increases the height but not the width:

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Anyone know how to increase the `MatBottomSheet` width?  [Stackblitz new window demo.](https://angular-matbottomsheet-demo-with-styling.stackblitz.io)

Note that the demo has to run in a new window (Open in New Window) in order to see that the `MatBottomSheet` is not full view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because you have `mat-bottom-sheet-container-large` applied to the same element which is having css

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container-large {
     min-width: 512px;
     max-width: calc(100vw - 256px); 
}
```

remove this class  or add !important property to `min-width` in your `mat-bottom-sheet-container` class

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw !important;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome the `!important` works and it's the perfect solution as Angular Material controls the CSS.  I don't see `.mat-bottom-sheet-container-large` in the class list for the element.  Are you seeing it  on the `mat-bottom-sheet-container` element?

Comment: yes, i see it on `mat-bottom-sheet-container` element may be it's applied base on screen size bcs when i resize it down `mat-bottom-sheet-container-large` change to `mat-bottom-sheet-container-medium`

Comment: Ah - Got it - It's a responsive utility - Thanks again!!

Comment: this will cause the bottom sheet to flicker on mobile, angular material team should remove the default height of `max-height: 80vh`

Answer (score 2):

Better instead of CSS overwriting `.mat-bottom-sheet-container`, you can use your own custom CSS class for every bottom sheet and pass that class to the `MatBottomSheet` with the `panelClass` attribute in the configuration object.

```
this.myBottomSheet.open(MyComponent, {
  panelClass: 'my-component-bottom-sheet'
});
```

In your global `styles` you define your custom class:

```css
.my-component-bottom-sheet {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw !important;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

And so you can define separate classes for each bottom sheet.

Answer (score 0):

So for something like this, when you want to edit the size, it's easiest to wrap your bottom sheet component in a div, and set the min-width on that - rather than trying to override the outer/parent width.

HTML:

```
     <div class="bottom-sheet-containter">
        //Bottom sheet content
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .bottom-sheet-containter {
      min-width: 80vw !important;
    }
```

I had ran into the same problem but this solution worked perfectly for me.